# Next JS and Firebase Hosting - How to set custom domain for SSR

Tags: firebase, next.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I'm using the brand new Firebase feature which allows now to deploy Next JS apps on Firebase and use SSR.

I followed the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/nextjs?hl=en) and I'm able to deploy.
As a result, Firebase deploys to Hosting and creates an HTTP Cloud Function that needs to be called in order to access the website.

My problem is that I don't manage to use a custom domain or even the default one provided by firebase hosting.

My firebase.json is currently set as such:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "ssrfunction"
      }],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there something that I miss?

Comment: Can you explain what does it mean "I don't manage to use a custom domain or even the default one provided by firebase hosting"?